Error: NEXT_REDIRECT when trying to signin
I have this auth.config:
import type { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth";

export const authConfig = {
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ auth, request: { nextUrl } }) {
      console.log(nextUrl);
      const isLoggedIn = !!auth?.user;
      const isOnDashboard = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/in");
      if (isOnDashboard) {
        if (isLoggedIn) return true;
        return false;
      } else if (isLoggedIn) {
        console.log(nextUrl);
        return Response.redirect(new URL("/in", nextUrl));
      }
      return true;
    },
  },
  providers: [],
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;

Whenever I try to login/sigIn with my server actions:
export async function authenticate(
  prevState: string | undefined,
  formData: FormData
) {
  try {
    await signIn("credentials", formData);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof AuthError) {
      switch (error.type) {
        case "CredentialsSignin":
          return "Invalid credentials.";
        default:
          return "Something went wrong.";
      }
    }
    if (isRedirectError(error)) {
      console.log(error);
      throw error;
    }
    throw error;
  }
}

I get the following error:
{
  error: Error: NEXT_REDIRECT
      at getRedirectError (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect.js:49:19)
     ..............................
      at async Server.requestListener (C:\mypc\programming\MINE\payroll\payroll-next\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:141:13) {
    digest: 'NEXT_REDIRECT;replace;http://localhost:3000/en/login;303;',
    mutableCookies: p { _parsed: [Map], _headers: [_HeadersList] }
  }
}
 POST /en/login 303 in 432ms

I think it could be the problem I use i18n but it is working good. Is it possible to be from my file structure?

